# deploy error app no maping audit with Envers hibernate and wildfly 27

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, wildfly

I am trying to launch an application from jenkins on a wildfly 27 server and I receive the error that is attached in the image. The strange thing is that if I launch it locally it works fine for me the error occurs in the integration with jenkins the application is launched but I don't know create the tables please thank you very much
[maping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVAMk.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LecS2.png)

If anyone has any idea of ​​the error I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.